# Why do some 2nd decl. "-er" adjectives and nouns drop the "e" in the stem?

Tags: phonetics, declension, noun, adjective, morphology

Is there any rule explaining why certain second-declension nouns and adjectives with a nominative *-er* ending drop the *e* when declined (e.g. *ager*, *liber*, *pulcher*), and why others keep it (e.g. *puer*, *socer*, *līber*)? ([A fuller list of these nouns](http://www.thelatinlibrary.com/101/Declension2.pdf).)

That it has to do with a phonetic pattern seems to be contradicted by phonetically similar words falling in either category, e.g. *adulter, adulterī* vs. *culter, cultrī*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is well-known and virtually all good grammars discuss this (as vowel syncope).

**Genetivus singularis** helps us reconstruct the original nom.sg. form (*synchronically*), that's why we learn nouns in Latin in two forms, nominativus singularis and genetivus singularis.

**Type A.** No change, the vowel was present in all forms.

Nom. sg. pu**e**ros > *pu**e**rs > pu**e**r

Gen. sg. pu**e**ri

**Type B.** Originally, there was no e in Nom. sg.

Nom. sg. agros > *agrs > ag**e**r

Gen. sg. agri

Data from Old Latin and other Indo-European languages (especially Ancient Greek) confirms this.

**Environment:**

1. consonant + *-ros, e.g. SAKROS > sacer (cf. ferus);
2. vowel + *-ros (in trisyllabic words, short penult), e.g. *vesperos > vesper (cf. sincerus)

etc.

For further details see Weiss 2009/2011, Chapter 23; Baldi 2002: 313; Meiser 1998, §55.1, and Sihler §74.4.

Comment: Thanks! A few of the cited pages: Baldi - https://books.google.com/books?id=5iP7F7isnA8C&pg=313. Sihler - https://books.google.com/books?id=u8C7GqCt494C&pg=PT159. And another source (Hale & Buck 1903): https://books.google.com/books?id=g49fAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA21.