# Why homicide instead of hominicide?

Tags: classical-latin, derivation, morphology

The word *homicida* is attested in classical Latin, and the English "homicide" is an obvious loan.
The word seems to come from *homo* and *caedere*.
Why is the first part *homi-* instead of *homini-*?
The stem of *homo* appears to be *homin-*, not *hom-*, and I'm not aware of any special role of *‑in-*.
Are there other similar examples that might help understand this by analogy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Others more versed in historical linguistics may offer a more nuanced offer, but *-cida*, like a good many suffixes, are attached to the nominative and not formed from the root. The *-i* instead of *-o* is then due to weakening of an unaccented vowel. Cf. *musculus*, *muscerdae*, *minusculus*, or *paterculus*, all of which are formed from the nominative.

I'm not sure if this has been suggested (de Vaan is unhelpful), but I imagine forms like *matricida* were based on analogy with *parricida*, which despite its late meaning likely did not come from *pater*. de Vaan further notes (pp. 447-448):

> The absence of syncope to **parkaida* suggests *parricida* is a relatively recent compound. For a recent formation, *par* 'equal' is the most obvious candidate.

Comment: When you say that *musculus* and *minusculus* are formed from the nominative, do you mean just synchronically, or also diachronically? The words *mus* and *minus* do seem to have historically had /s/ in their stems, although by the time of Classical Latin this had been rhotacized to /r/. So it seems hard to me to tell if the *s* in the diminutive forms was originally from the nominative

Comment: @sumelic I am under the impression that it's historical. *Paterculus* would be a more solid example. I cannot speak to why it's *Agricola* or *iunonicola*, though, and I hope that others could fill in gaps there. Alas, my Sihler is packed away and out of reach.

Comment: With "agricola", I think it's related to what AlexB says in the following answer about "ager" originally having agr- in all forms (with the nominative form "agros") https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/382/9 while "pater" had a vowel between the "t" and "r" in at least some forms in PIE

Comment: @sumelic Ah, that does make sense. None of that would be helpful, though, without some sense of when these words formed. More research is needed.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know of an accepted answer to this question, but I will offer two alternative possibilities:

1) It's merely a case of phonetic simplification, i.e., an earlier **hominicida* was replaced by *homicida* simply because the latter was easier to say. This is known as haplology.

2) If the PIE ancestor of L. *homo* goes back to something like **(dh)ghemon*, then one can *possibly* imagine a combining form **homi-* derived from a zero-grade **gh(e/o)mn̥*, but since the regular reflex of PIE *n̥* is *en*, this would work only assuming an irregular dropping of the *n* in this word, which makes it a lot less likely than possibility (1).