# Why 'Vir' is the only word of 2nd declension with -ir ending?

Tags: classical-latin, vocabulary, etymology, second-declension, research

I'd like a detailed explanation of the word 'Vir' denclesion. Vir is the only word of the second denclension with 'ir' ending.  What is the reason for this phenomenon? Anyone knows a research about it who could give me a link?

| Case | Singular | Plural |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Nominative | vir | virī |
| Genitive | virī | virōrum |
| Dative | virō | virīs |
| Accusative | virum | virōs |
| Ablative | virō | virīs |
| Vocative | vir | virī |

Comment: My initial guess is that it's by analogy with the *-er* nouns (which, unlike *vir*, are a regular development) to avoid homophony with *virus*, but I'm not sure off the top of my head if that works out historically. (I guess *virus* has a long *i*, though.)

Comment: The gaelic word for man is "fir" which is essentially the same word. In the usual case when a foreign word is adopted it takes the third declension. Other Gaelic words that may have come into Latin are aer ("air") and vatis ("fate").

Answer (score 18, accepted):

*Vir* developed its s-less ending from the process of syncope described in [Alex B.'s answer to "Why do some 2nd decl. "-er" adjectives and nouns drop the "e" in the stem?"](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/382/9): its original form is reconstructed as **vĭros*, but in this and many other words an original **-ros* was contracted, or sycopated, to *r.* (Probably via intermediate steps like **-ros* > **-rs* > **-rr* > **-r*.) My understanding is that this syncope did not occur when **-ros*  was preceded by a long vowel; thus, *vērus, sērus, mīrus, dīrus, vīrus* should be phonetically regular.

I don't know of any strong reason to suppose that this process was irregular in the context of nouns ending in **-ĭros.* But that starting point itself doesn't seem to have been common.

---

I can hardly find any Latin nouns ending in *-ĭrus* with short *ĭ*, aside from rare words that look like borrowings such as *Semirus* (a river name). In borrowings, *-ĕrus* also may occur without syncope, e.g. *Cerbĕrus* (from Greek Κέρβερος).

I think the most frequent *-ĭrus* word is *pĭrus*, but there are a number of ways to explain why this word would have developed differently from **vĭros.* This root of *pirus* is believed to be borrowed, although I guess the borrowing was fairly old. [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pirum#Latin) says the /r/ in Latin *pirus/pirum* is probably from rhotacism of original **pis-* (I guess based on comparison with Greek forms *ᾰ̓́πῐον* and *ᾰ̓́πῐος* which would show the Greek loss of intervocalic *s), and it's conjectured that syncope of Latin **-ros* was not regular in cases where *r* comes from original *s. Aside from that, even if *pirus* had ever met the conditions to be subject to syncope as a regular sound change, I can think of a few reasons why a form like *pĭr* might get analogically replaced with *pĭrus*:

- The word is feminine, but second-declension words ending in *r* in the nominative singular *r* are pretty much all masculine.
- The word corresponds to the neuter *pirum,* which obviously does not show syncope, and there could be pressure towards using the form *pirus* by analogy with other fruit-tree pairs such as *pōmum, pōmus; arbutum, arbutus; mālum, mālus.*

Compare *cedrus* and *citrus,* two other feminine second-declension plant names that end in *-rus.*

---

Michiel de Vaan (2008)'s entry on *ferus* implies that the syncope in *vir* is regular, while suggesting it did not occur in *ferus* due to analogy:

> The retention of *-rus* (as opposed to *vir* < **viros*) must be due to the influence of f. *fera,* n.pl. *fera.*

(*Etymological Dictionary of Latin and the other Italic Languages*)

But I find it odd to suppose that *fera* had a significant influence on *ferus*, considering that the regular forms ending in *-(e)ra* of any 1st/2nd adjective in *-er* evidently did not prevent these adjectives from generally developing syncopated masculine nominative singular forms.

Like de Vaan, Sihler 1994 implies that syncope should be considered the regular outcome for original disyllables with a short vowel followed by **-ros* by saying *merus* and *ferus* "have not been explained" (*New Comparative Grammar of Greek and Latin,* §74.4).

On the other hand, Weiss 2009 (cited by [Cairnarvon's answer here](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/18630/9)) argues that the retention of *-us* in *ferus* is regular due to it being a disyllable and that the loss of **-os* in *vir* is irregular and caused by analogy to *puer* "boy", *gener* "son-in-law", *socer* "father-in-law" (*Outline of the Historical and Comparative Grammar of Latin,* Chapter 23 "The Latin Nominal System; the Second Declension", §III. "Case endings", page 221). This hypothesis seems to have been [previously espoused by Ferdinand Sommer](https://books.google.com/books?id=tZINAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA94) (*Handbuch Der Lateinischen Laut-Und Formenlehre*, 1902, [page 364](https://archive.org/details/handbuchderlate00sommgoog/page/364/)).

But I am skeptical that such a common word as *vir* would have been remodeled based on the forms of these less frequent words, especially since *-us* was still the most common second-declension masculine nominative singular ending and was found at the end of other words for male family members such as *fīlius* "son", *avus* "grandfather; ancestor".

In the end, because there are so few examples of words with the relevant forms, I doubt it's possible to determine with certainty which outcome was regular.

---

(*vir* isn't actually quite the only example: there is also an obscure word *lēvir/laevir*, "brother-in-law", mainly attested in glosses that define what it means, but it is thought that it ends in *-vir* only because its form was altered by analogy with the word *vir.* This is the source of the obscure English word *levirate*. There are also, of course, the actual compounds of *vir* such as *sēmivir, triumvir,* etc.)