# 'Aurifer' or 'Auriferus'?

Tags: translation-check, word-comparison, contemporary-latin, declension, neuter

What is the masculine form of "Aurifera" ?

I supposed it was "auriferus":

Tibicen auriferus is like a goldish beetle.

http://www.masscic.org/sightings/cicadas/tibicen-auriferus-in-topeka-ks

Well this word exists, it seems right.

But my dictionary starts this words as 'Aurifer, -a-um'. Aurifer, not auriferus

Answer (score 8):

Yes, the correct form is *aurifer*, though in early Old Latin it would have been **auriferos* (actually **ausiferos*), as you'd expect.

For second-declension nouns with stems ending in *r* (original *r*, not rhotacised *s*), there was a rule in late Old Latin saying the ending *-os* of the nominative singular would be lost in certain cases (and if that meant the word ended in a consonant + *r*, an epenthetic *-e-* would be inserted). According to Michael Weiss' *Outline of the Historical and Comparative Grammar of Latin*, those cases are:

1. If a consonant precedes *-ros* (Old Latin *sakros* > Classical Latin *sacer* 'sacred').
2. If a vowel precedes *-ros* and the word is at least trisyllabic with a short penult (*vesper* 'evening' < **vesperos* and *līber* 'free' < **loiberos*, but *ferus* 'wild' and *sincērus* 'sound, whole').
3. The word *vir* 'man', which may be analogical to *puer* 'boy', *gener* 'son-in-law, *socer* 'father-in-law'.

In all other cases, the *-os* is regularly preserved (and *-os* regularly became *-us* around the 3rd century BCE). *Aurifer* falls under the second case, and *Tibicen auriferus* got its name from a modern scientist who misapplied analogy.